# Why do my monitors make this popping/cracking sound?

Tags: keyboard, speakers

I just bought a keyboard and some monitors to output the sound so I don't know much about this.  But when I hit too many keys on the keyboard, it makes this popping and cracking sound, I don't know what the term is but I'm sure there is one because my laptop makes that noise too when I turn it up too loud.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the output from your keyboard is too loud which is overdriving the input of your monitor's amplifier and causing clipping/distortion. Try turning your keyboard's volume down and then turn the volume of your monitors up to compensate for the keyboard's volume decrease.